# How to get that $F(t)$ also satisfies $ F(t)=1+\int_0^t\left(C^{-1}-2F(\tau)f'(F(\tau)\right)d\tau, (*) $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If for function $F(t)$ satisfies
$$
F(t)=\frac{1}{R(t)}(1+C^{-1}\int_0^tR(\tau)d\tau)
$$
where $R(t)=\exp(2\int_0^tf'(K(u))du)$ and a constant $C>0$.

How to get that $F(t)$ also satisfies
$$
F(t)=1+\int_0^t\left(C^{-1}-2F(\tau)f'(F(\tau)\right)d\tau, (*)
$$

---

Note that
$$
R'(t)=R(t)\times2f'(K(t))
$$

If I take derivative on both sides of $F(t)$, I will get
$$
F'(t)=-\frac{R'(t)}{R^2(t)}+C^{-1}(-\frac{R'(t)}{R^2(t)}\int_0^tR(\tau)d\tau+\frac{1}{R(t)}R(t))
$$
that is
$$
F'(t)=-\frac{2f'(K(t))}{R(t)}+C^{-1}(-\frac{2f'(K(t))}{R(t)}\int_0^tR(\tau)d\tau+1)
$$

But how to get the result in (*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are quite close. Here's how I do it (assuming functions here have sufficient regularity). Note that $$F(0) = 1$$ since $$R(0) = 1$$ by the formulas provided. Now, we compute by Quotient Rule,
$$\begin{aligned}F'(t) &= \frac{C^{-1}R(t)^2 - R'(t)(1+C^{-1}\int^t_0 R(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau)}{R(t)^2} \\ &= C^{-1} - \frac{R'(t)}{R(t)}\frac{(1+C^{-1}\int^t_0 R(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau)}{R(t)}. \end{aligned}$$
From the expression for $R(t)$, we compute its derivative as you have obtained above. Rearranging, we have
$$\frac{R'(t)}{R(t)}=2f'(K(t)).$$
Also, observe that
$$\frac{(1+C^{-1}\int^t_0 R(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau)}{R(t)} = F(t).$$
Combine these to obtain
$$F'(t) = C^{-1} - 2f'(K(t))F(t)$$
and apply Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to obtain
$$\begin{aligned}F(t) &= F(0) + \int_0^t C^{-1} - 2f'(K(\tau))F(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau \\ &= 1 + \int_0^t (C^{-1} - 2f'(K(\tau))F(\tau)) \mathrm{d}\tau\end{aligned}$$
as required.